# getLogs RPC makes filters?

Tags: parity, memory

I am stuggling with memory explosion issue of Parity on my EC2 instance.
The memory usage of it keeps increasing gradually.

I suspect that `getLogs` API call makes some garbage on the node. But I couldn't get similar issue report from anywhere. Furthermore, I am not a Rust developer that can find the issue from the code.

I call `getBlock`, `estimateGas`, `sendRawTransaction`, etc, besides `getLogs`. But no filter related calls.

Could you tell me whether the calls made the memory explosion or there is any other reason? Anyone suffered from the same issue on Parity?

Comment: You would likely get more help opening an issue on their github repo.

Comment: I wanted to get a casual answer from the community. Anyways I will open an issue. Thanks!

Comment: I can't recall any such issues at all. And I was infact using multiple getLogs some of which at times each caught 5% of all the transactions.